# How to preserve newlines when creating .ics?

Tags: visualforce, event, outlook

I created a simple apex page to generate an Outlook calendar ics file from an Event. I then created a button in my Event to run that page. Everything works fine BUT when I open my new outlook invitation, it appearently doesn't keep the carriage returns entered in the Event's Description field and shows my description field text as a long and unique line.

Like this:

> Line1Line2Line3

instead of:

> Line1
>   Line2
>   Line3

Here is my apex page code:

```
<apex:page title="Add to Outlook" contentType="text/calendar" cache="false">
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP;TZID=GMT:<apex:outputText value="
{!SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($CurrentPage.parameters.start,':',''),'-',''),' ','T')}"/>
UID:<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($CurrentPage.parameters.start,':',''),'-',''),' ','')}"/>-1@salesforce.com
DTSTART;TZID=GMT:<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($CurrentPage.parameters.start,':',''),'-',''),' ','T')}"/>
DTEND;TZID=GMT:<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($CurrentPage.parameters.end,':',''),'-',''),' ','T')}"/>
SUMMARY:<apex:outputText value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.subject}"/>
DESCRIPTION:<apex:outputText value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.description)}"/>
LOCATION:<apex:outputText value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.location}"/>
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER:-PT15M
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
</apex:page>
```